Can we anticipate $\sum_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}\min(i,j)=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$ without computation?
Define, for all positive integer $n$ :
$$S_n=\sum_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}\min(i,j)$$
A simple calculation leads to the following closed formula :
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^\star,\,S_n=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$which is notoriously equal to $\displaystyle{T_n=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}$.
My question : Is it possible to anticipate the relation $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^\star,\,S_n=T_n$ without doing any computation ?

Consider stacking boxes into a pyramid, with each layer being a square one unit larger than the last, but they are all shoved against a corner instead of being centered. Now your first sum is counting the height of each column, while the second sum is the number of boxes at each layer.

Yes, this is expected.
Let's stack some cubes of $n$ layers with two sides at a corner of a room.
At the bottom layer, we have a square of size $n \times n$.
At the second bottom layer, we have a square of size $(n-1) \times (n-1)$.
For the case of $k$-th level from the top, we have a square of size $k \times k$.

Source of picture
For small cases:
We have
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
The matrix of the left contains  $\min(i,j)$ where the terms on the right show the layers of cubes.
It is counting by columns vs counting by layers.

Consider the following $n\times n$ grid
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
1 &1 &1 &1 &\ldots &1\\
1 &2 &2 &2 &\ldots &2\\
1 &2 &3 &3 &\ldots &3\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &\ldots &4\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
1 &2 &3 &4 &\ldots &n
\end{array}$$
where the $(i,j)$-th entry is $\min\{i,j\}$.
Now strip off each layer (of $1$s and then $2$s and so on) and sum them separately. That will give
$$1\times (2n-1) + 2\times (2n-3) + 3\times (2n-5) + \dots + n\times 1$$
which can be re-interpreted as
$$(2n-1) + (2n-3) + (2n-3) + (2n-5) + (2n-5) + (2n-5) + \dots$$
and since the sum of the first $n$ odd integers is $n^2$, you have your proof.

I think what you're saying is$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\min\left{i,,j\right}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\left(2n+1-2k\right)\&=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\left(n+1-m\right)\left(2m-1\right)\&=\sum_{l=1}^{n}l^{2}.\end{align}$$

@J.G. yes, but in a more visual way

This answer generalizes the question.
Call the sum $S$ for the case asked. Consider a tuple $(a,b) \in \mathbb N^2$ where $1\le a,b\le n$. Consider some $r \in [1,n] \cap \mathbb N$. For how many tuples $(a,b)$ is $\min(a,b) = r$? You can construct exactly $(n-r+1)^2 - (n-r)^2$ such tuples$^{*}$. Thus the sum is just
$$\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{r=1}^{n} r((n-r+1)^2 - (n-r)^2) \\ 
&= \sum_{r=1}^{n} r(n-r+1)^2 - \sum_{r=1}^{n} r(n-r)^2  \\
&= \sum_{r=1}^{n} r(n-r+1)^2 - \sum_{\color{red}{r=0}}^{n} r(n-r)^2\\
&= \sum_{r=1}^n (n-r+1)r^2 - \sum_{r=0}^n (n-r)r^2\tag{1.1}\\
&= \sum_{r=1}^n (n-r+1)r^2 - \sum_{\color{red}{r=1}}^n (n-r)r^2\\
&= \sum_{r=1}^n r^2
\end{align}$$
REMARKS:
$^{*}$: the most important aspect of the solution is counting the number of tuples where $\min(a,b)=r$ is obeyed. To count them first count all the tuples where $(a,b) \in \{r,r+1,r+2,\dots, n\}^2$ and then subtract all tuples where $(a,b) \in \{r+1,r+2,r+2, \dots, n\}^2$. This counts all tuples where $\min(a,b) \geq r$ and then subtracts all tuples where $\min(a,b)\geq r+1$.
$(1.1)$ uses the fact that $\sum_{r=a}^{n} f(r) = \sum_{r=a}^n f(n-r+a)$. This is called reversing the order of the sum.
I provide two bonuses;

Claim $1$: $S_1(k,n) = \underset{1\le x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_k \le n}{\sum} \min(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots, x_k) =\sum_{r=1}^n r^k$

Setting $k=2$ in this case yields the desired identity asked in the question.
Proof: Consider all $k$-tuples $\in \mathbb N^k$ where all their elements are in $[1,n]$. There are exactly $(n-r+1)^k - (n-k)^k$ such $k$-tuples which have their minimum element some fixed $r$. Since $r\in [1,n] \cap \mathbb N$ we have
$$\begin{align}
S_1(k,n) &= \sum_{r=1}^n r((n-r+1)^k - (n-r)^k) \\
&= \sum_{r=1}^{n} (n-r+1)(r)^k - \sum_{r=1}^n (n-r)(r)^k \\
&= \boxed{\sum_{r=1}^n r^k}
\end{align}$$

Claim $2$: $S_2(k,n) = \underset{1\le x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_k \le n}{\sum} \max(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots, x_k) =n^{k+1} - \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} r^k$

Proof: As usual, there are exactly $r^k - (r-1)^k$ $k$-tuples such that the tuple's maximal element is some $r\in[1,n]\cap \mathbb N$ where the $k$-tuples are $\in \mathbb N^k$ where each element $\in [1,n]$. Thus
$$\begin{align}
S_2(k,n) &= \sum_{r=1}^n r(r^k - (r-1)^k)\\
&= n^{k+1}+\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}r^{k+1} - \sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(r+1)r^k\\
&= \boxed{n^{k+1}-\sum_{r=1}^{n-1} r^k}
\end{align}$$

Although the answer looks long and it isn't a sleek visual proof, I still argue that the answer did not involve any "computations" which was requested by OP. I just used some re-arrangements of summations and elementary combinatorics.

For a fixed $k$, there are precisely $2(n-k+1) - 1$ tuples $(i,j) \in [n] \times [n]$ such that $\min(i,j) = k$. Thus, the sum can be expressed as
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \times (2(n-k+1) - 1) = \sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1) \times (2k - 1) $$
A number $2k-1$ is contributing to this sum $(n-k+1)$ times. We can visualize this as a stacked sequence of rows of decreasing length where row $1$ has $n$ repetitions of $1$, row $2$ has $n-1$ repetitions of $3$ and so on.
The result $S_n = T_n$ is apparent by instead summing this construction column-wise and recalling that the sum of the first $k$ odd numbers is $k^2$. The latter fact can be shown purely combinatorially.
